# Prove $10x-cos(4x)$ to be continuous in the interval $[0,0.1]$

Tags: calculus, continuity

How do I prove $f(x) = 10x - cos(4x)$ to be continuous in the interval $[0,0.1]$?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @Mindlack I rewrote the question completely.

Comment: Prove it to be $1263$-Lipschitz continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ is continuous, $cos$ is continuous, by linearity, your function is continuous.

Comment: You should probably note that constants, $+$ and $\times$ are continuous, too.